# Set background color based on the value of a data attribute

Tags: html, jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

I have 16 different `section`-tags. Every `section`-tag has a `data-` attribute to set a specific background-color for each `section`:

```
<section data-color="#A3D1B5">
```

Now I want to set this color as the background.

**What I've already tried:**
In *[CSS values using HTML5 data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523197/css-values-using-html5-data-attribute)*, the answer says it should be possible to set the color like `background: attr(data-color);`, but this won't work for me.

I took a look at `jQuery data()` but I don't know how to set the background for all of the `section`-tags.

Are there any other solutions to handle this with jQuery's `.data()`?

Comment: Not an answer, so it goes as a comment: `attr` is for use only in `::before` and `::after` generated content: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1044862/148412

Comment: the question I really would like to ask is why not use a classname?

Comment: Because i load this sections with ajax and it's easier for me to handle it. And i think there are less lines of code when i add just 1 statement to set the background...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bs35L/)

```
$("section").css('background', function () { //or for code's consistency, i'd use background-color instead
    return $(this).data('color')
});
```

Comment: Interesting approach but not that fast comparing it with an `each` loop: http://jsperf.com/each-vs-return1

Comment: @Steve That's correct, i appreciate this kind of comment :) Even in your case, you should use object data not attribute.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer / comment. Combined, the best solution! `+1` to both of you :P

Answer (score 3):

Try this code,

```
$("section").each(function(){
    $(this).css('background',$(this).data('color'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZcPYv/

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the `data-color` attribute and assign it to the `background` in the css:

```
$('section').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background', $(this).attr('data-color'));
});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pk5dK/

Comment: @mplungjan you can do it with both, but `attr` seems to be faster than `data` when retrieving the data.

Comment: `+1`, and I would expect just using `this.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('data-color');` as the function body to be even quicker.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/JgfkY/

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#section").css("background-color",$("#section").attr("data-color"));
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<section id="section" data-color="#A3D1B5">Section with custom color</section>
```